# Php artisan migrate in command prompt is bringing errors when I want to migrate Laravel project to my second computer

Tags: laravel, project, migrating

*When I tried this code in command promt in my directory of laravel project: php artisan migrate: I always get this error warnig what is the reason and how I an fix it:* **PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely got different PHP version installed on other machine and that version is too old. Compare versions with `php --version` and upgrade.

Comment: Oh, I cheked this and the php versions in both of my pc were various.Then, I tried to run it in cmmand prompt but it is not working.